# Freeze grid when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid that has a checkbox for each row,when i select the checkbox its does some search in the grid,so i have i little delay,less then a second,but if the user check a lot of box fast,for example 5,it marks all 5,but when the process finish it it go back and mark only one.I need something that freeze the grid when the first one is marked,i tried some JS but didn`t work.This is part of my grid.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden">
            <asp:GridView runat="server" AllowSorting="true"  class="Tabelas" Width="700px"  ID="grdSimulacao" OnRowDataBound="grdSimulacao_OnDataBound" DataSourceID="odsResultado"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader"    CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="grdSimulacao_PageIndexChanging">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="TabelasHeader branca-10NN"  HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>  
                <RowStyle CssClass="TabelasBody grid" ></RowStyle> 
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="TabelasBodyAlt grid" BackColor="#EEEEEE"></AlternatingRowStyle>        
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Todos" >

                        <HeaderTemplate />


                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnTodos" Text="Todos" Width="50px" CssClass="button" runat="server" OnClick="btnTodos_Click" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkSeleciona" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSeleciona_OnCheckedChanged"  ToolTip='<%# Bind("calculo") %>'
                                Enabled='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("checkbox_status")) == true) ? false : true %>' Checked='<%# Eval("checkbox") %>' AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />

                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Vinicius, hello. You can create a invisible div on top of the grid to make it unclickable on the starting of the request, and then remove it at the end.

Comment: Didn't work,i need something that is JS,if i use codebehing is not working,when the user starts clicking in every checkbox,i need to disable the grid  fast the first checkbox is clicked.